# Possible custom axis scale?

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to set my own scale for numerical results?

I need to set the scales with these values 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000

Comment: There isn't an axis property that allows for this. You have to use a workaround. If you're using v3, you have to create guides to draw lines at specific values on your axis and disable the axis' generated labels. v4 requires axis ranges to do the same thing. If you can specify what version you're using, I can post an example.

Comment: I use v4 I will be grateful for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AmCharts v4 doesn't provide a way to directly influence the scale outside of setting [`minGridDistance`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/#Setting_the_density_of_the_the_grid_labels) on the axis. A workaround for this is to disable the axis' own generated labels and create your own using [axis ranges](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Ranges_as_guides). You'll also want to set your own min/max values on the axis.

```
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.min = <your min value>;

range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.value = <axis value>;
range.endValue = range.value;
range.label.text = range.value; 
// ... repeat for each axis increment

valueAxis.max = <your max value>;
```

Here's a basic demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "value2": 362,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 269,
  "value2": 450,
  "value3": 841
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 700,
  "value2": 358,
  "value3": 699
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
  "value": 490,
  "value2": 367,
  "value3": 500
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
  "value": 500,
  "value2": 485,
  "value3": 369
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 6),
  "value": 550,
  "value2": 354,
  "value3": 250
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 7),
  "value": 420,
  "value2": 350,
  "value3": 600
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
valueAxis.min = 0;

var rangeValue = 50;

for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
  range.value = (rangeValue += ((i + 2) * 25));
  range.endValue = range.value;
  range.label.text = range.value; 
}

valueAxis.max = rangeValue;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  
  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
  bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
}

createSeries("value", "Series #1");
createSeries("value2", "Series #2");
createSeries("value3", "Series #3");

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```